# JSON Parsing Error for Schema.org Structured Data

Tags: json, parsing, syntax-error, schema.org

I'm an SEO just getting into manual structured data building, so apologies if I come off as a newb here.

Working on this JSON code an**I keep getting parsing errors.

The error seems to be at line 125, but I think the object's brackets are closed and commas in the right place.

Lines 124-133

```
     "@type": "HowToStep",
          "position": "2",
          "itemListElement": [
            {
              "@type": "HowToDirection",
              "position": "1",
              "text": "Research the business you want an appointment with"
            },
```

I've tried ensuring all the brackets were closed and that commas were placed on all key:value pairs except for the last key:value pair of an object or array - using parsing tools like validator.schema.org/ , json-ld.org/playground/ ,  and search.google.com/test/rich-results keep telling me there's a missing "," "}" or "]" but the key:value pairs, objects, and arrays all look right to me.

I can provide the whole code if needed for more context.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: The whole code is here for context 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZhLWi9IhN7QR0CEhLY0fi_s3avzZAlcX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have 2 problems: JSON structure; schema.org logic. Here is an accurate subset: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1etWLO2gJLnMW86OpTVdAi0cceW5fLNVPeFRmhuCRTvM/edit?usp=share_link. You should use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON. You need to implement the schema.org grammar - see subset.

Comment: You can check the subset here to see the grammar errors: https://validator.schema.org/